# Office.js Callback breaks Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, powerpoint, office-addins, office-js

I am working on an PowerPoint-AddIn using AngularJS. To get the Users Language i use Office.context.displayLanguage which is only available inside the Office.initialize -Callback. I get my Language-Strings through an Angular-Factory. When I put the Office.initialize -Callback inside my Angular Controller it breaks the Controller-Functionality and no Buttons on my Page will work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```
myApp.controller('angularHomeController', ['$scope', 'lang', function ($scope, lang) {
    $scope.lang = lang.getLocaleStrings("en-US");
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $scope.lang = lang.getLocaleStrings(Office.context.displayLanguage);
    }
}]);
```

I set the language by default to English, but I want that to be changed when the Document is initialized and i can access the displayLanguage. My App works fine until I put the Office.initialize -Callback inside of my Controller. Should I be injecting the Office-Object somehow? I don't get any Error-Messages.

Comment: I'm having kind of the same issue, I have an `outlookService` (angular) where I do all my `Office` calls. But the function `Office.initialize` never gets called. Still working on it, I found this on the web : http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/07/27/load-angularjs-after-office-initialized/ keep me up to date. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue as I mentioned in the comments.
You just have to declare `Office.initialize` in your `<head>` tag and bootstrap your angular module inside it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Add the following script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Office.initialize = function (reason) {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['myOfficeModule']);
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Other scripts -->

</head>
<body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** There is no longer need for `ng-app="myOfficeModule"` while you are bootstrapping manually.

It works for me, now the `Office` object is accessible from my services. I hope it works for you too.

Source used : http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/07/27/load-angularjs-after-office-initialized/

Comment: Elfayer code must work. angular app should fire manually after Office.initialize event

Comment: @Elfayer Once I did that office is initializing successfully but Angular events and models don't work. can you please help?